# Проблема с диском, подключенным по iscsi

Tags: proxmox

Добрый день.

К машине (proxmox 3.4, Linux 2.6.32-39-pve) подключен раздел по iscsi. Размер раздела 5Tb. 
При работе с этим разделом в dmesg и syslog сыпется такое сообщение:

```
kernel: sd 7:0:0:0: [sde] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
```

С этим можно что-то сделать? Или не обращать внимание?